# Swift - setting dictionary value to nil confusion

Tags: swift, dictionary

I'm quite confused:

Let's create a dictionary:

```
var d = ["foo": nil] as [String: Any?]
```

Now if I want to remove the key `"foo"`, I can just do

```
d["foo"] = nil // d is now [:]
```

And other option could be:

```
let x: String? = nil
d["foo"] = x // d is now [:]
```

But this behaves differently:

```
let x: Any? = nil
d["foo"] = x // d is still ["foo": nil]
```

Similarly to the above (which I think is the same):

```
d["foo"] = d["foo"] // d is still ["foo": nil]
```

What is going on? And btw, why does swift let us delete keys with setting them to `nil`, instead sticking with

```
d.removeValue(forKey: "foo")
```

?

Comment: What is you Swift version?

Comment: I'm running swift 3

Comment: In Objective-C all keys and values of a dictionary must not be `nil`. Swift dictionary is supposed to work similarly. Just don't use optional values ;-)

Comment: Ah! That's so frustrating! I'm writing Swift so I don't really care about the Objective C logic. If I'd care I'd be writing Objective C...

Comment: @vadian: However it still looks like an inconsistent behaviour. Why a `nil String?` removes the entry while a `nil Any?` keeps `nil`?

Comment: @appzYourLife Indeed it is. We should make a proposal ... ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove a key in a dictionary of type `[A: B]`, you need to set its value to an element of type `B?` of value `nil`

For instance:

```
var d = ["foo": 1] as [String: Int]
let v: Int? = nil
d["foo"] = v // d is now [:]
```

or simply

```
d["foo"] = nil // here nil is casted to Int?
```

So if we now have

```
var d = ["foo": nil] as [String: Any?]
```

`A` = `String` and `B`=`Any?`

to remove the key/value associated to `foo`, we need to set the value to a type `B?` = `Any??` of value `nil`:

```
let v: Any?? = nil
d["foo"] = v // d is now [:]
```

What happens when we do

```
d["foo"] = nil
```

is that here `nil` is casted to `Any??` and not `Any?`, so its actually different from doing

```
let v: Any? = nil
d["foo"] = v // d is still ["foo": nil]
```

and that's why the results are different.

Thanks @sliwinski for opening the discussion with apple that linked us to https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=12

Answer (score 9):

Given a dictionary like this:

```
dict: [String: String?] = []
```

If you add `nil` value like this:

```
dict["a"] = nil
```

The dictionary will be empty. However, if you add a `nil` value like this:

```
dict["a"] = nil as String?
```

The dictionary will **not** be empty. Try it out...

```
func testDictionary() {
    var dict: [String: String?] = [:]

    dict["abc"] = nil
    print("dictionary is empty -> \(dict.isEmpty)") // -> true

    dict["abc"] = nil as String?
    print("dictionary is empty -> \(dict.isEmpty)") // -> false
}
```

This seems very odd behavior and a subtle difference. Can someone explain?

Answer (score 3):

```
/// If you assign `nil` as the value for the given key, the dictionary
/// removes that key and its associated value.
```

This is a sentence from the documentation, so as you can see it is by design. If this not fit your needs then you are doomed to use `updateValue(value: Value, forKey: Hashable)` which also works more predictable.

What I found is that when you use `NSMutableDictionary` instead of `Dictionary` then it works as "expected"

```
let ns = NSMutableDictionary(dictionary: d)
let x: Any? = nil
ns["foo"] = x // ns {}
```

However `let x = Any? = nil` case seems that there is a bug in Swift implementation at least to version `Apple Swift version 3.0.1 (swiftlang-800.0.58.6 clang-800.0.42.1)`

Btw. when all elements from `Dictionary` are removed, `type` of `Dictionary` is still correctly recognised

```
let x: String? = nil
d["foo"] = x // d is now [:]
let m = Mirror(reflecting: d) // Mirror for Dictionary<String, Optional<Any>>
```

I allowed myself to add bug to Swift lang: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-3286

Comment: Thanks for your response and opening the bug. I'm curious to see what they say